# OpenWrt (Chaos Calmer 15.05.1): `opkg install <package> -d ram` is failing

Tags: package-management, openwrt, opkg

When I try to install python-xml using
`opkg install python-xml -d ram`

It goes through the following steps:

- Installing... [WORKS]
- Downloading... [WORKS]
- Configuring... [FAILS]

The "configuring" step fails with errors...

`grep: /usr/lib/opkg/info/<package>.control No such file or directory 
cat: can't open '/usr/lib/opkg/info/<package>.list' No such file or directory`

The files `opkg` is looking for are in the directory: `/tmp/usr/lib/opkg/info`

**PROBLEM:** `opkg` should be looking to the `/tmp` directory when using the `–d dest_name` parameter

Does anyone know how to get the "configuring" step to use `/tmp` as the root?

*NOTE: I found an [open ticket](https://dev.openwrt.org/ticket/20646) on openwrt.org, but it doesn't specify a workaround.*

Answer (score 2):

when installing on ram you must change this on /etc/opkg.conf

```
option overlay_root /overlay
```

for

```
option overlay_root /tmp
```

and the installation will proceed sucessfully